# gae python cannot delete tasks from the default queue

Tags: google-app-engine

Queue seemed to jam up. Very large number of retries of with:

47:32.546 /_ah/mapreduce/controller_callback 200  325ms  0kb AppEngine-Google; (+xxx://code.google.com/appengine) 
0.1.0.2 - - [14/May/2013:14:47:32 -0700] "POST /_ah/mapreduce/controller_callback HTTP/1.1" 200 124 "xxx://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-ok-alone.appspot.com/_ah/mapreduce/controller_callback" "AppEngine-Google; (+xxx://code.google.com/appengine)" "ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-ok-alone.appspot.com" ms=326 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000014 queue_name=default task_name=appengine-mrcontrol-15811304617282FD9E118-1182 pending_ms=100 app_engine_release=1.8.0 instance=00c61b117ce38007a896105636da1be48f70e6db

'xxx' replaces 'http'

Ran out my data write quota very rapidly though my data writes are actually tiny and few, relatively. What caused this problem? How to fix it?

I am using just the default queue without any modifications.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue.  I fixed it by manually deleting the unsuccessful jobs in the default Task Queue on the admin console.